# Битые символы в строках Си

Tags: c

Простецкая программка по генерации случайных слов-паролей обернулась мне болью в пятой точке.
Сразу предоставлю свой овнокод:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
//Создаю массив из символов для паролей =>
char t[] = {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M','.','*','_'}; 

char randc(int u, char k[20]) //Выбор случайного символа из массива
    {
        int r;
        r=-1+rand()%sizeof(t);
        k[u]=t[r];

        return k[u];
    }

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i, j, n, m;
    printf("Insert count of words:");
    scanf("%d",&n); //Ввод кол-ва строк-паролей
    printf("Insert size of words(less than 10 recommend):");
    scanf("%d",&m); //Ввод длины этих строк
    char s[m],f[160],qs[]=", "; //Массив случайной строки; Большой массив для всех случайных строк; Строка-разделитель

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++) //Создание случайного слова
                {
                    s[j]=randc(j,s);
                    printf("%c",s[j]);
                }
            strcat(f,s); //Соединяю слова в одну строку
            strcat(f,qs); //Ставлю после каждого слова в строке разделитель
        }
    printf("\n%s",f); //Вывожу полученную из нескольких строк строку
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке сделать слова длиннее трех, я получаю битые символы.
[image]
Но при попытке сделать их длиннее шести, начинает пыхтя работать.
[image]
Причины сея чуда я не представляю.
Я уверен, найдутся люди не обделенные извилинами, которые, надеюсь, мне помогут.

Comment: Основная ошибка в том, что вы не завершаете строки (массивы символов) нулями. В начале напишите `f[0] = 0;`, затем, после цикла по `j` напишите `s[m] = 0;`. Увеличьте размеры массивов --  `s[m + 1], f[(m  + 2) * n + 1]`. Да и упростите `randc()` до `char randc() { return t[rand() % sizeof(t)]; }`

Comment: Если вызывать rand большое количество раз за короткий промежуток времени он выдает одинаковое число (про крайней мере у меня было так. не знаю точно с чем это связано, либо оптимизация компилятора либо сама реализация rand) мне в это случаи помогло : unsigned int tick; __ asm __ __ volatile __("rdtscp; shl $32, %%rdx; or %%rdx, %%rax":"=a"(tick)::"%rcx", "%rdx"); srand(tick);

Comment: @noname2019: "Если вызывать rand большое количество раз за короткий промежуток времени он выдает одинаковое число..." - так не бывает. А то, что вы описываете - это результат широко распространенной элементарной "пионэрской" ошибки: странной идеи вставить вызов `srand(time(NULL))` перед вызовом `rand()`. Разумеется, будет одно и то же число...

Comment: Чисто на будущее, строки можно инициализировать вот так `f[160]={0,}` - тогда в строке не будет мусора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> r=-1+rand()%sizeof(t);
> ```

Почему вдруг `-1`??? Откуда взялось это слагаемое `-1`? Из-за этого теоретически время от времени вы будете получать `-1` в `r`. Тогда доступ в массив `t` по такому индексу `r` будет попадать в несуществующий элемент `t[-1]`. Поведение не определено.

> ```
> printf("Insert count of words:");
> ```

Не "Insert", а "Enter".

> ```
> s[j]=randc(j,s);
> ```

Это не ошибка, но это странно. Насколько я помню, вы не в первый раз это делаете в своем коде.

Ваша функция `randc` и так уже помещает свой результат в `s[j]` (т.е. в `k[u]`, которая есть `s[j]`). Достаточно просто вызова `randc(j,s)`. Не надо еще делать присваивание в `s[j]`.

Либо (лучше) перепишите вашу `randc` как функцию без параметров, которая возвращает случайный символ. Тогда здесь вы будете делать просто `s[j]=randc()`.

Либо так, либо эдак. А сейчас у вас какое-то масло-масляное получилось.

> ```
> strcat(f,s);
> ```

Так нельзя. Функция `strcat` умеет работать только со *строками*. К этому моменту ни `f`, ни `s` не являются строками - в них нет нулевого терминатора. Поведение не определено.

Comment: То есть для того, чтобы s и f были строками, требуется просто добавить нулевой терминатор '\0' в конец каждой переменной?

Comment: @Eugene_lamer, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим способом(не без помощи добрых людей, конечно):

```c
for(i=0;i<sizeof(s);i++) f[i]='\0'; //Заполнил большой массив нулевыми терминаторами, так как без них в начале вывода большой строки выводит битые символы
```

Далее также добавил в конец каждой случайной строки нулевой терминатор:

```c
for(j=0;j<m+1;j++) //j>m+1 для нулевого терминатора
                {
                    s[j]=randc();
                    if(j==m) s[j]='\0'; //В конец строки нулевой терминатор
                    else printf("%c",s[j]);
                }
```

Также я поменял на более рентабельный вид функцию случайного символа:

```c
char randc()
    {
        return t[rand()%sizeof(t)];
    }
```

Спасибо всем, кто заинтересовался моим вопросом и кто мне помог.